# cycles glass acting odd

Tags: glass

the glass is acting odd
[image]
the faces are oriented the right way
[image]
so i thought it was because of the odd geometry
[image]
and i dissolved those
[image]
so im stuck can someone help me

Comment: try increasing the mean crease or adding edge loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try clean up that topology around the bottom of the glass - rather than those stretched areas, delete those faces and try clean loops, it will help even out the subdivision surface. Use edge loops or Inset (I) as required.
[image]

Comment: with a little bit of fiddling it worked